# How to pass a function to active option of jquery ui tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

How to pass a function to jquery ui tabs active option?

I can pass a function to jquery ui tabs activate option like this

```
activate: function(event, ui){
    localStorage.setItem("#" + $(this).context.id + "-current-index", $(this).tabs('option', 'active'));
}
```

How to get these value using active option, below code is not working

```
active: function(event, ui){
    localStorage.getItem("#" + $(this).context.id + "-current-index")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review the `.getItem()`. I would suggest the following:

```
function getData(i){
  return localStorage.getItem(i);
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
active: function(event, ui){
  ui.newPanel.html(getData("#" + $(this).context.id + "-current-index"));
}
```

**Update**

> **activate( event, ui )** Type: tabsactivate
>
> Triggered after a tab has been activated (after animation completes). If the tabs were previously collapsed, `ui.oldTab` and `ui.oldPanel` will be empty jQuery objects. If the tabs are collapsing, `ui.newTab` and `ui.newPanel` will be empty jQuery objects.

See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

`ui.newPanel` is the jQuery Object that represents "*the panel that was just activated.*" So we can then use `.html()` on that object.

> **.html( htmlString )**
>
> Description: Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/html/